# Should I use a "WithEvents variable" in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

This code should send these form strings as an email once the submit button on the form is clicked. However "EcampusIssuesSubmit.Click" gives the error "handles clause requires a withevents variable". Here are some more details:

- According to Microsoft's msdn,I need to add a "WithEvents variable",
  but in the past I haven't needed to do so.
- Normally in visual studio when you click the button form control it brings you to the code file page,but here it gives the message "Could not complete action".
- I've included the asp code just in case, but I don't think it's the source of my error.

  **Here is the VB code:**

  Imports System.Net.Mail

  ```
  Partial Public Class EcampusMain
      Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

      Protected Sub EcampusIssuesSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EcampusIssuesSubmit.Click
          ' Gather Variables
          Dim strfirstname As String = "First Name: " + firstname.Text
          Dim strlastname As String = "Last Name: " + lastname.Text
          Dim strnetid As String = "NetID: " + netid.Text
          Dim struin As String = "UIN: " + uin.Text
          Dim strphone As String = "Phone Number: " + phone.Text
          Dim strcurrentdate As String = "Date: " + currentdate.Text
          Dim strissueday As String = "Date of Issue: " + issueday.Text
          Dim strinstructorname As String = "Faculty/Instructor Name:" + instructorname.Text
          Dim stremail As String = "E-mail: " + email.Text
          Dim strcontactpref As String = "Preferred way to contact: " + contactpref.Text
          Dim strecampSect As String = "ECampus Class Name & Section:" + ecampSect.Text
          Dim strbldanroom As String = "Building & Room Number: " + bldanroom.Text
          Dim strcomputer As String = "Computer Number:" + computer.Text
          Dim strbrowser As String = "Web browser being used: " + browser.Text
          Dim strproblem As String = "problem Description: " + problem.Text
          Dim strhumanity As String = humanity.Text
          ' E-mail Prep
          Dim body As String = strfirstname & strlastname & strnetid & struin & strphone & strissueday & strinstructorname & stremail & strecampSect & strcomputer & strproblem
          Dim ourEmail As String = "Eforms@website.edu"   'Change back

          ' Check the humanity of the submitter 
          ' Change back Turtles!
          If strhumanity = "Turtles!" Then
              ' Send Email
              Using message As New MailMessage()
                  message.From = New MailAddress(ourEmail.ToString())
                  message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("george123@yahoo.com"))    'Change back
                  message.Subject = "Ecampus Isses"
                  message.Body = body
                  Dim client As New SmtpClient()
                  client.Host = "127.0.0.1"   'Change back
                  client.Send(message)
              End Using

          Else
              'exit
          End If
      End Sub

  End Class
  ```

  **Here is the asp code**

  ```
  <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="EcampusIssue.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default"  %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">


      <style type="text/css">
          .auto-style1 {
              text-align: center;
          }
          .auto-style2 {
              text-align: center;
          }
      </style>


  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <center>   <div>

          <h1 style="font-size: xx-large; text-align: center">
              Ecampus Problem Report</h1>
          <h2 style="font-size: x-large; text-align: left">
              <strong>Student/Faculty Contact Information</strong></h2>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              First Name<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vfirstname" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="firstname"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              Last Name<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="lastname" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vlastname" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="lastname"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              NetID<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="netid" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vnetid" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="netid"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <p class="auto-style2">
              UIN<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="uin" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vuin" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="uin"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <p class="auto-style2">
              Phone Number<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="phone" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vphone" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="phone"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <p class="auto-style2">
              Date<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="currentdate" runat="server" Width="249px"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              Date of Issue<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="issueday" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              Faculty/Instructor Name<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="instructorname" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vinstructorname" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="instructorname"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              Your E-mail<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vemail" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="email"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <p class="auto-style2">
              Preferred way to contact you?<o:p></o:p></p>
          <p class="auto-style1">

              <asp:RadioButtonList ID="contactpref" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="44px" Width="85px">
                  <asp:ListItem>E-mail</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>Phone</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:RadioButtonList>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
          <p class="auto-style2">
              ECampus Class Name &amp; Section<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="ecampSect" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vecampSect" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="ecampSect"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <p class="auto-style1">
              Building &amp; Room Number<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="bldanroom" runat="server" Width="301px"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
          <p class="auto-style1">
              Computer Number<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="computer" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>
          <p class="auto-style1">
              Web browser being used<o:p>:</o:p></p>
          <p class="auto-style1">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="browser" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="300px">
                  <asp:ListItem>FireFox</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>Chrome</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>Internet Explorer</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>Opera</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>Other(Include in description)</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
              <o:p></o:p>
          </p>

          <p class="auto-style1">
              Please describe your issue:<o:p></o:p></p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
              <asp:TextBox ID="problem" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="200px"></asp:TextBox>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </p>
          <p class="MsoNormal">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="vproblem" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="problem"
    ErrorMessage="This is a required item."
    ForeColor="Red">
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


              <br />
              Please verify your humanity by typing &quot;Aggies!&quot; in the box below (case sensative):<br />
              <asp:TextBox ID="humanity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              <o:p>
              <br />
              <asp:Button ID="SciFairSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
              </o:p>
          </p>


      </div>
     </center>  
  </asp:Content>
  ```

Comment: what is `EcampusIssuesSubmit` exactly?

Comment: To ellaborate on @Plutonix question, the ASP you provided does not contain this _Button_ in it. What is EcampusIssuesSubmit? If it is a button, where have you declared it, because again, it is not in your ASP so _IT_ is not doing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem seems to be this:

```
Partial Public Class EcampusMain
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub EcampusIssuesSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles EcampusIssuesSubmit.Click
```

The "handles clause requires a withevents variable" message is saying that VS believes that `EcampusIssuesSubmit` is not something that actually clicks, ie it does not have events. Or it has been renamed or this event handler has been moved.

If `EcampusMain` is not the same class as that where the button is, then you may have hidden the click event from it.

One way to test this, and maybe fix it is to change that event sub to a method:

```
     Friend Sub EcampusSendIssue()
       ... all your code
     End Sub
```

Then call this from the standard button click

```
    Sub Button_Name_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
         Handles Button_Name.Click

        EcampusSendIssue
    End Sub
```

It partly sounds like you have a scope problem, so it is possible that the next error is that the click event wont be able to find the new sub `EcampusSendIssue` and/or the new sub wont be able to find firstname, lastname etc.  But at least you will know what the problem is - it is hard to tell without knowing more about how this is structured